# Index error: tuple index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-3.6

when i convert .py to .exe , anyone help

```
name_input = input('type your name')
print_number = int(input('input number'))

for x in range (print_number):  
    print (name_input)
```

Comment: You must run as administrator, open the cmd as administrator

Comment: @eyllanesc another error when i convert py to .exe , IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: That problem is not due to pyinstaller but to your code, I think you are accessing an element of the tuple that does not exist.

Comment: @eyllanesc But it work well when i run the program, 
btw , I just learned python yesterday and my second programming languange

Comment: If I do not see the code I can not help you

Comment: @eyllanesc It just like this

name_input = input('type your name')
print_number = int(input('input number'))

for x in range (print_number):
      print(name_input)

Comment: @eyllanesc code:

name_input = input('type your name')
print_number = int(input('input number'))

for x in range(print_number):
     print(name_input)

Comment: execute: `pyinstaller --onefile {your script}`

Comment: @eyllanesc the code on the question that i change :))

Comment: Could you tell me how you generate the executable?

Comment: Also you can not change the question, if you have a new one, create a new post.

Comment: @eyllanesc what mean generate executable?  I only have 1 reputation, i'm new in here(stack overflow)

Comment: I thought that your code had no problems but it seems that not, now what I am thinking is that you are using improperly pyinstaller

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @eyllanesc mean the problems when i'm installing pyinstaller or what?

Comment: I think the problem is the way you use pyinstaller.

Comment: Any other tools that i need for pyinstaller? I install pyinstaller pip

Comment: @eyllanesc can i contact you with app chat like facebook or line? I think maybe you can help me much

Answer (score 0):

Apparently pyinstaller does not YET support python 3.6.
I run into this problem just today.. same issue.
The administrator rights access does not solve it.